# How to make a circle of curves?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do you create this using illustrator? (without all the fancy background effects etc., just the shapes.).

[image: Example image]

I want to create a bunch of curved lines which together form a circle.
How do I align every curve perfectly aligned to the center?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw circles, some of them with different and maybe irregularly dashed strokes, align them, rotate and add the effects. Some of the strokes seem to be outlined, too. See the following cartoon:

[image]

You can also add anchor points to solid circles and then by the direct selection tool select + DEL some segments. That must be done after the circles are aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply create a circle with a thick stroke, outline it, then use the pathfinder tool to get rid of the segments you don't want.

or

you could make a circle and using the pen tool add points to create arcs you want to delete. delete them and make the remaining segments thick and then outline.

there's many ways to do this